# Reading Soap response using C# WPF

Tags: soap, xml-parsing

I have the following response from a SOAP message. I need to read the values from the REQUEST_STATUS tag and the RESULT tag and put it in a datatable to update the table inside my database.

Please help me as I am doing this for the first time.

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <CalculationResponse xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/">
       <OUTPUT>
         <REQUEST_STATUS>
           <IS_SUCCESS>true</IS_SUCCESS>
           <IS_PARTIAL_SUCCESS>true</IS_PARTIAL_SUCCESS>
         </REQUEST_STATUS>
       <RESULT>
          <Value>
              <inset1>1<inset1>
         </Value>
         <Value>
              <inset2>2<inset2>
         </Value>
       </RESULT>....
```

C# Code I tried:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\out.xml");
XNamespace ns = @"http://www.someurl.com/";
bool validation = false;
var root = doc.Descendants("CalculationResponse").Elements("OUTPUT").Elements("REQUEST_STATUS");
var valuestr = from r in root.Elements("IS_SUCCESS")
            select r.Value;
 validation = (valuestr.ToString()=="true")?true:false;
```

I always get the valuestr has no results in the collection.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need the C# logic to read the values and put it in a datatable

Comment: OK, Thanks, for that, So what have you tried to do so far, and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: Sorry for that. I missed to add that. Now I have updated in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I made it to achieve:

C# Code:

```
XNamespace ns = @"http://www.someurl.com";
bool validation = false;
var parent = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "CalculationResponse").Descendants(ns + "OUTPUT");
var valuestr = (from r in parent.Descendants(ns + "REQUEST_STATUS").Descendants(ns + "IS_SUCCESS")
               select r.Value).ToList();

validation = (valuestr[0] == "true") ? true : false;
```